# Need to print highest year and their highest quarter in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, limit, max

I have a requirement to print the corresponding highest year and highest quarter for a given column.

Input is in a table:

```
cityprogram          year          quarter
===========          ====          =======
Abc                  1998             1
Abc                  1999             4
Abc                  1999             4
Abc                  1998             3
xyz                  1998             4
xyz                  1998             1
xyz                  2000             3
```

It should print

```
Abc                 1999             4
xyz                 2000             3
```

I tried many joins, max conditions, I seem to get quarter 4 and 4 for both of them :( thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a [**window function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like `ROW_NUMBER` in a common-table-expression:

```
WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT [cityprogram], [year], [quarter],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                   PARTITION BY [cityprogram]
                   ORDER BY [year] DESC, [quarter] DESC)
     FROM dbo.TableName 
)
SELECT [cityprogram], [year], [quarter]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfa87/2/0)

```
CITYPROGRAM     YEAR    QUARTER
Abc             1999      4
xyz             2000      3
```

`ROW_NUMBER` returns only one row per group even if there are ties(cityprograms with the same highest year+quarter). If you then want to show all highest you can replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.